# What am I doing wrong with this JavaScript parsing code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a simplistic HTML editor for part of my website without things like Ace or TinyMCE. The problem is that when I'm using local storage, the save function appears to work, but the view function is not changing the notes to the saved notes.

I made a JSFiddle for all of you, at [this URL](http://jsfiddle.net/nlh101/cqvf3x4x/1/).

Here is my HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Begin Section 1: Metas -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- End Section 1: Metas -->
    <!-- Begin Section 2: Scripts -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nprogress/0.1.3/nprogress.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://secure.quantserve.com/quant.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ladda-bootstrap/0.1.0/ladda.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ladda-bootstrap/0.1.0/spin.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.2/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- End Section 2: Scripts -->
    <!-- Begin Section 3: Stylesheets and Links -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.1.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nprogress/0.1.3/nprogress.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico|Open+Sans|Roboto|Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ladda-bootstrap/0.1.0/ladda.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="stylesheets/app/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- End Section 3: Stylesheets and Links -->
    <!-- Start Section 4: Required Elements -->
    <title>Superpad Editor</title>
    <!-- End Section 4: Required Elements -->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container animated bounce">
        <div class="errors"></div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-brand-centered">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered"><span class="brand-logo">Superpad</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-brand-centered">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">        
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save">Save Notes</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="view">View Saved Notes</button>
        </div>
        <div contenteditable class="content-editable normal editor"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my JavaScript (it uses jQuery):

```
NProgress.start();
mixpanel.init("<CENSORED FOR SECURITY>");
mixpanel.track("Page Loads");
NProgress.done();
$(document).ready(function(){
if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
    console.log("L.S.W.");
} else {
    $(".errors").append("<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;<\/span><span class="sr-only">Close<\/span><\/button><strong>Oh snap!<\/strong> Local Storage doesn't work on your browser. Saving won't work, so you might want to keep this open if you want to keep your notes.<\/div>");
    NProgress.done();
};
$("#save").click(function() {
    localStorage["note"] = JSON.stringify($(".editor").html());
});
$("#view").click(function() {
    if (localStorage["note"] != null) {
        var contentsOfOldDiv = JSON.parse(localStorage["note"]);
        $(".editor").    
        $("div.fifth").replaceWith(contentsOfOldDiv);
    } else {
        $(".errors").append("<div class=alert alert-info alert-dismissible> role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;<\/span><span class="sr-only">Close<\/span><\/button><strong>Heads up!<\/strong> No save was detected. Did you save before?<\/div>");
    };
});
});
```

So what am I doing wrong (I got the JSON parsing idea from another Stack Overflow subject!)?

Comment: can you provide a link to a jfiddle?

Comment: Can you make the title of the question more specific? I think it makes it easier for people to find this solution if they have a similar question in the future.

Comment: Making your questions title bit constructive would help you more as well as other users to understand the issue

Comment: For starters the lines beginning with `$(".errors").append("<div class="alert alert-dange...` contain numerous unescaped double quote characters within your string. Doing this will cause random string termination throughout your statement, not to mention its syntactically incorrect and will throw an error. Have you checked your browser's console for errors? You should have some...

Comment: Can you narrow the source of your question down, and only provide that code which is directly involved?

Comment: Actually @War10ck, I did check! The console had errors from the nProgress library, but nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several syntax issues. For example the lines below:

```
$(".errors").append("<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;<\/span><span class="sr-only">Close<\/span><\/button><strong>Oh snap!<\/strong> Local Storage doesn't work on your browser. Saving won't work, so you might want to keep this open if you want to keep your notes.<\/div>");
```

and

```
$(".errors").append("<div class=alert alert-info alert-dismissible> role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;<\/span><span class="sr-only">Close<\/span><\/button><strong>Heads up!<\/strong> No save was detected. Did you save before?<\/div>");
```

You need to escape the `"` character or use a single quote. That might not solve your issue, but it's a start. Your code is failing when execution reaches that line, and it can't continue, which might explain why you aren't getting the expected result.

Try using your browser developer tools to find any errors in your code. [This page](http://devtoolsecrets.com/) has some information on finding and using the dev tools in your browser. The error in the JSFiddle is shown as:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

If you fix the quotation issues, you then get the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: mixpanel is not defined
```

Keep going through the errors in your console and see if you can narrow down the issue that way.

Comment: Okay- I will try this. I will respond if I get any progress.

Comment: I solved everything but the dot notation errors. I then tested it with that and it still didn't work! Any ideas?

Comment: Also, in my latest version I replaced the `.append` errors with the Bootstrap modal code that I added. It removed quite a few different errors.